# Is this question on-topic here (does it make sense to migrate it)?

Tags: discussion, scope

[This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/507355/conceptual-question-of-dual-simplex-method) will probably never get a useful answer at CV, but will it be well received here?

Comment: It won't be unless the OP at least shows their efforts in solving the problem.

Comment: Also, I think the question is misstated.

Comment: Question shows little to no effort and would not be valuable for the OR.SE community without some more work by the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On topic? yes. A good question? no. We don't like to be asked to simply answer a homework question for someone. See [Can I ask a homework question on OR.SE?](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/229/38).